# Is the British National Grid and LAEI 2008 Grid the same?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I am not completely sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but I cannot find any sources confirming the differences between the LAEI 2008 Grid and the British National Grid. How would I convert the LAEI 2008 Grid to longitudes and latitudes?

### Edit

I am referring to the 2019 emissions summary here:

https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-atmospheric-emissions-inventory--laei--2016

Comment: I can't find any information on LAEI 2008 Grid. Where did you find it?

Comment: duplicate https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/is-the-british-national-grid-and-laei-2008-grid-the-same

Comment: @Mapperz I'll delete that one..

Comment: @Pointdump In the CSV files for the 2019 emissions summary: https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-atmospheric-emissions-inventory--laei--2016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean `London Atmospheric Emissions Inventory (LAEI) 2008 Concentration Maps` as available from https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/laei-2008-concentration-maps  then yes the data I looked at, for example `LAEI08_NO2a`, is using British National Grid (EPSG:27700) as the CRS